# Unable to play video in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I need to play the video using "MPMoviePlayerViewController" when i pick a video from library and pass its URL to player, it plays for around 2 seconds and stops responding (No interactions at all), and found these lines in console

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
```

I have already tried everything found in "stackoverflow", But no use, Can any one please suggest me the solution.

Device : iPad-3, version : 6.1

Please suggest

Here is the code that i am using from playing video

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        [self playVideoWithURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
    }
}


- (void)playVideoWithURL:(NSURL*)fileURL
{
    if(!self.playerViewController)
    {
        self.playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
        [self.moviePlayerContainer addSubview:self.playerViewController.view];
        self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
        self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        [self.playerViewController.moviePlayer stop];
    }
    else
    {
        self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL = fileURL;
    }

    CGRect movieFrame = self.moviePlayerContainer.frame;
    movieFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
    self.playerViewController.view.frame = movieFrame;
}
```

Comment: could you post some of your code where you set the MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code which is used for playing the video.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening simply because that movie is not locally stored but attempted to be progressively downloaded via iCloud.

Your network bandwidth (towards iCloud) doesn't cope with that video as its demands are too high.

Without your log you see lines like this:

> Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0

That is like a early warning from the player, telling you that it will most likely not load data fast enough for a fluid playback.

The other important part is this line

> [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media
>   item ID: 0

That one tells you that the system is remotely downloading the movie. It is trying to make sure that other possibly parallel downloads should be waiting for this one but obviously that does not free enough bandwidth (as there just is not more available).

I am afraid, there is nothing you can do about it directly.

You need to download that video from iCloud first or you need to reduce its quality (re-encoding).

Comment: But i am not loading the video file from iCloud, it is locally stored in video from "Camera roll".